# Flash CS5 Dynamic Text Incorrect Values

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I did not have any problems on CS4 but I encountered this error below when I used CS5.

Fonts should be embedded for any text that may be edited at runtime, other than text with the "Use Device Fonts" setting. Use the Text > Font Embedding command to embed fonts.

I managed to solve the line of error after help from Rup, Fox and Stephen.

Now that the line of error is cleared. However, I am still having problems with my dynamic text fields which worked with correct values in CS4 but gave the incorrect values in CS5.

Help anyone? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well let me clear you one thing, you need to embed font for input and dynamic text field. static text-field works fine without embedding. now if you create dynamic text-field using new operator , the fonts of the text-field must be embedded also. Embed the font first , set linkage option and use Font Class to load the embedded text then assign this loaded font to dynamically created text-field.. it will work.